# The definition of trace-class operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace

A trace-class operators are defined on a separable Hilbert space. However, is it possible to define trace or trace-class operators on an arbitrary Hilbert spaces? I am just curious...

Comment: Yes. Which concerns do you have ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Definition including this, most texts I have encountered is restricted to the separable case only.

Comment: So, is it meaningful to define trace or trace-class operators in more general cases? Also, does it still holds that the set of trace-class operators form a banach space and its dual space is the banach algebra of bounded operators?

Answer (score 3):

In Chapter 16 of *"Introduction to Functional Analysis"* by Meise & Vogt (1997), the trace class gets introduced on arbitrary infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces ($\mathcal G,\mathcal H,\ldots)$. Basically, every compact operator $A:\mathcal G\to\mathcal H$ has a [Schmidt representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition#Bounded_operators_on_Hilbert_spaces)

$$
Ax=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n(A)\langle e_n,x\rangle f_n
$$

with a non-negative, decreasing null sequence $(s_n(A))_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ *(singular values)* and orthonormal systems $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ in $\mathcal G$, $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ in $\mathcal H$. Then the trace class is defined as

$$
\mathcal B_1(\mathcal G,\mathcal H):=\Big\lbrace A:\mathcal G\to\mathcal H\text{ compact}\,|\,\Vert A\Vert_1:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n(A)<\infty\Big\rbrace.\tag1
$$

One then can define a trace on $\mathcal B_1(\mathcal H)$ as usual. Now

- the trace norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ actually is a norm. *(Corollary 16.15 in Meise/Vogt)*
- $\mathcal B_1(\mathcal G,\mathcal H)$ is a Banach space with respect to the trace norm. *(Corollary 16.24)*
- The dual space $\mathcal B_1(\mathcal G,\mathcal H)'$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathcal B(\mathcal H,\mathcal G)$ by means of the map $\Psi:B\mapsto\operatorname{tr}(B(\cdot))$. *(Proposition 16.26)*

One can also show that in the case of separable Hilbert spaces, (1) is equivalent to the usual definition

$$
\mathcal B_1(\mathcal H)=\big\lbrace A\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\,|\,\operatorname{tr}\sqrt{A^\dagger A}<\infty \big\rbrace
$$

see e.g. Theorem VI.21 in *"Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics. I: Functional Analysis"* by Reed & Simon (1980).

Answer (score -1):

Now this looks like a separable space: you pick a basis that is infinite but countable. A non separable space has uncountable bases. Now, provided you have a proper measure theory, your sum might generalise to an integral. But as Keith is, I'm eager to see examples.

The reason why is that operators on non-separable spaces are likely to be in type III von Neumann (W*-)algebras. In particular, such non-separable spaces decompose as the direct sum of uncountably many different separable subspaces. The result is that the rank of projectors on these subspaces is infinite, just as the rank of the identity operator is. As a result, it seems difficult to even define a trace on these operators.

But this is mainly gut feeling. So if examples were identified, that would be great.

Comment: If what you wrote refers to my answer from 2018, then I would like to clarify that the Schmidt representation holds for compact operators on **arbitrary** Hilbert spaces. Roughly speaking, compactness is the key to ensure that the operator acts only on "countably many dimensions", which in turn lets one define the trace over arbitrary orthonormal bases there. Actually, the trace class is—provably—the largest subspace of the bounded operators where the trace can be defined in a meaningful way.

Comment: Thanks Frederik for the explanation. This calls for two questions 1) do you have a reference I could quote for the Schmidt representation in arbitrary Hilbert spaces? Everything I can find focuses on the separable case. And 2) what is the measure that is used to replace the sum when dimensionality is non countable? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: As written in my original answer, my go-to reference for this is Meise & Vogt's "Introduction to Functional Analysis" (1997), specifically Chapter 16 therein. Alternatively you can have a look into Ringrose's "Compact Non-Self-Adjoint Operators" (1971), although I don't like that book *as* much (it's still good though). For the second question: the sum is at most countable, regardless of the cardinality of the Hilbert space; that's the whole point of compactness. So there's no need for any advanced measures

Comment: I wonder whether the fact that trace class operators eventually decompose onto a countable set of components is related to the fact that non separable spaces built by infinite direct product of separable spaces do break down into the direct sum of uncountably many separable spaces ('sectors', 'incomplete direct products'  see von Neumann 1938 'on infinite direct products'). In which case, could the trace class operator be limited to such a sector (or a finite number thereof)? Has this been investigated?

Comment: There *should* be no relation between these constructions. The point is that trace-class operators can only act (non-trivially) on countably many dimensions because, else, they would violate compactness. As a consequence, such an operator necessarily vanishes on the other dimensions of the Hilbert space, independent of "how large" the Hilbert space is/the dimension of $({\rm ran}A)^\perp$